# Компиляция через makefile на удаленной машине в Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, json, компиляция, visual-studio-code

Ситуация: на локальной машине стоит [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) ,из под нее правится проект на удаленной машине через ftp.

Вопрос: как настроить компиляцию проекта на удаленной машине и отладку на локальной с помощью [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)?

По сути все что требуется это запустить make на удаленной машине и подцепиться к дебагеру на ней. Запустить make можно к примеру с помощью task.json скрипта, что то в духе:

```js
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "make",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "Makefile",
            // Make this the default build command.
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
            "showOutput": "always",
            // No args
            "args": ["all"],
            // Use the standard less compilation problem matcher.
            "problemMatcher": {
                "owner": "cpp",
                "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
                "pattern": {
                    "regexp": "^(.*):(\\d+):(\\d+):\\s+(warning|error):\\s+(.*)$",
                    "file": 1,
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "severity": 4,
                    "message": 5
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Но как это запустить на удаленной машине, а так же отладка удаленная - данные вопросы не очень ясны.

Comment: Думаю, что никак. Лучший вариант - сделать RDP на удаленную машину.

Comment: Если удаленная машина под Linux, то сборку можно запустить через ssh, отладка - через gdbserver.

Comment: ос на вашей и удаленной машине какие? какой дебаггер там стоит, и т.д. имеете ли вы права админа там, можете ли добавить софт? это вопрос нехитрой автоматизации, до которой вы бы и сами могли догуглиться. `google://expect ssh powershell remote debug  (visual studio/gdb)`

Comment: ОС моя - Ubuntu, удаленная - QNX 6. Дебагер соответственно gdb есть. Права админа есть, вообще машина крутится в VirtualBox. Софт я могу конечно добавить, но хотелось бы добавлять по минимуму, т.к. практика показывает что любая установка софта не заточенного под QNX на эту ОС - очень муторное дело, а часто и не возможное.

Comment: **kmv**, если не сложно, то можно немного поподробней как это сделать именно из под VSCode? Нужно создать task.json определенного формата или еще какие то действия?